# Store all objects of a Jlist into a Array<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist, jlist

I've been searching and searching everywhere but can't find a way to solve this out.
The problem i'm facing is simple , I have created a ArrayList .. and transfered this object into a Jlist1 ( dont know if im doing something wrong but i have transfered all the objects of the ArrayList , and attached on this jList as string objects fields). I have a Button for transfering this jList1's selected items into another jList2 .. and I wanna give this button the function to Store the objects transfered in jList2 from the jList1 ... 
Down below I will print most important parts of the problem I explained.

The population of the jList1 code :

```
 ArrayList<Item> itemlist = items.getItems();

for(Item d : itemlist){
        itemlist_model.addElement( d.getItemID()+"      "+ d.getItemName()+"           " +d.getItemPrice() + "$"  );
        }//end for 
        ItemList_jList.setModel(itemlist_model);
}
```

The code i made for transfering selected items from jList1 to jList2 :

```
for(Object d: ItemList_jList.getSelectedValuesList()){
    //System.out.println(d);
    basketlist_model.addElement(Arrays.toString(ItemList_jList.getSelectedValues()) + "" );
    }
    StoreBasketList_jList.setModel(basketlist_model);
}
```

The code i'm trying to improve in order to store the jList2 objects into ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Item> ItemInBasket = new ArrayList<Item>();

 int len = basketlist_model.getSize();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                bw.write(basketlist_model.getElementAt(i).toString());
                ItemInBasket.add((Item) basketlist_model.getElementAt(i));
}
```

For making it  more simple to understand the code  : jList1 is ItemList_jList .. jList2 is StoreBasketList_jList .. and the ArrayList i'm trying to store these objects is ArrayList ItemInBasket . 
I've spent many hours trying to figure it out , would be thankful if someone could help me !

**NOTE** second jList is not empty , this proves it :
[image]

```
int counterelement = StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getSize(); System.out.println("The number of items in jList: "+counterelement); 
for (int i = 0; i < StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
ItemInBasket.add( (Item)StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getElementAt(i)); 
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MiserableVariable i need to store the objects of the jList2 into an ArrayList , how can i do that?

Comment: For everybody to understand the problem, you'd do well to try to get the indentation of the code in better shape. E.g. not leave out the '}' to match the '{' in the last section... (I hope this doesn't come across as too harsh :)

Comment: @JonasN is just matter of copying the code , i must have mised the last '}' .. but edited , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JList.getModel() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getModel--

```
JList jl = new JList(new Object[]{"a","b","c"});
System.out.println("jl.getModel().getSize() = " + jl.getModel().getSize());
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < jl.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    arrayList.add(jl.getModel().getElementAt(i));
}
System.out.println("arrayList = " + arrayList);
```

Prints out:

```
jl.getModel().getSize() = 3
arrayList = [a, b, c]
```

Comment: should i cast it in Item ??

Comment: It does not store the objects into arraylist  , after that part of code i implemented a "test code" to check if  arraylist was empty or not , and that arraylist is still empty

Comment: The ArrayList generated from the above is empty because the JList it is getting the data from was empty.  You should start with a JList that is not empty. You should print or check in a debugger the value of jl.getModel().getSize().  Example updated with to be non-empty start and print its result.

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot doesn't really prove anything. I can't see the code behind the GUI, so I can't see what variables have what values at the point in execution when they are accessed.

Comment: `int counterelement = StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getSize();
                System.out.println("The number of items in jList: "+counterelement);  /*proof that jlist is not empty */
                
                for (int i = 0; i < StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
                //Item itemtest = new Item();
                //itemtest.setItemID(9);
                
                ItemInBasket.add( (Item)StoreBasketList_jList.getModel().getElementAt(i)); // ItemInBasket.add()
                } ` this is a part of code

Comment: Put the code in your question not in a comment so it can be nicely formatted. Delete any commented out code. Add `System.out.println` statements to print variables i and ItemInBasket at the end of each iteration through the loop.

Comment: I added system.out.println(i); and it prints 0 , so this means the model list is empty... any idea where is the "bad code"

Comment: Printing 0 here does not mean the list is empty. It means that the loop only executed once with i having the value 0. If the size were three you should expect it to print 0 then 1 then 2 on separate lines unless it exited the loop for some other reason such as an exception. You should also print the ItemInBasket variable.

Comment: I solved it , each  object on jlist2 wasnt converting on item , so i made a loop for checking each objec on jlist 2 and his id , than  compared with the id of all items , and when this id equals database id i added the Database object instead of the jlist2 object .. but thank you for ur help :)